# Agregar un z-index a un elemento autogenerado

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un elemento autogenerado, el cual consiste de un dropdown para ubicar tus ciudades. Al momento de realizar el input, el codigo genera este dropdown prediciendo ubicaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mismo, necesito que al momento de generarse, lo haya con un mayor `z-index`, pero no reconozco el lugar en el que se genera.

El código relacionado es el sgte.

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    enterCity = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('enterCity'), {types: ['geocode']});

    enterCity.setFields(['address_components', 'geometry']);

    //Acá es donde creo que se genera y llena el dropdown
    enterCity.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    var place = enterCity.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        $("span[data-type=" + component + "]").html("");
    }

    country = "";
    region = "";
    city = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

        if (addressType == "country")
            country = place.address_components[i]["long_name"];
        if (addressType == "administrative_area_level_1")
            region = place.address_components[i]["long_name"];
        if (addressType == "administrative_area_level_2" && city == "")
            city = place.address_components[i]["long_name"];
        if (addressType == "colloquial_area")
            city = place.address_components[i]["long_name"];
        if (addressType == "locality")
            city = place.address_components[i]["long_name"];

        log(addressType + ": " + place.address_components[i]["long_name"]);
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            $("span[data-type=" + addressType + "]").html(val);
        }
    }

    $("#enterCity").val("");
    $("#locationSet").hide();
    $("#locationResult").show();
    log(place.geometry.location.lat() + ", " + place.geometry.location.lng());
    updateTimezone(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());

    $("#resultCity").html(city);
    $("#resultCountry").html(country);

    updateLocation(country, region, city, place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#style-autocomplete) el modal que se levanta tiene por clase `pac-container`

Entonces solo debes agregar una regla en tu CSS

```
.pac-container{
  z-index: 9999
}
```

Adicionalmente los otros elementos que se pueden modificar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

| Clase de CSS | Descripción |
| --- | --- |
| pac-container | Elemento visual que contiene la lista de predicciones que muestra el servicio de Place Autocomplete. Esta lista aparece como una lista desplegable debajo de los widgets de Autocomplete o SearchBox. |
| pac-icon | Ícono que aparece a la izquierda de cada elemento de la lista de predicciones. |
| pac-item | Un elemento de la lista de predicciones que proporcionan los widgets de Autocomplete o SearchBox. |
| pac-item:hover | La figura que aparece cuando el usuario coloca el puntero del mouse sobre un elemento. |
| pac-item-selected | La figura que aparece cuando el usuario selecciona un elemento a través del teclado. Nota: Los elementos seleccionados pertenecerán a esta clase y la clase pac-item. |
| pac-item-query | Un intervalo dentro de un pac-item que es la parte principal de la predicción. En el caso de las ubicaciones geográficas, contiene un nombre de lugar, como "Sídney", o un nombre y un número de una calle, como "10 King Street". En el caso de las búsquedas basadas en texto, como "pizza en New York", contiene todo el texto de la solicitud. De forma predeterminada, el pac-item-query se muestra de color negro. Si hay texto adicional en pac-item, este queda fuera de pac-item-query y hereda su diseño de pac-item. Su color predeterminado es el gris. El texto adicional normalmente es una dirección. |
| pac-matched | La parte de la predicción mostrada que coincide con la entrada del usuario. De manera predeterminada, el texto coincidente se resalta en negrita. Ten en cuenta que el texto coincidente puede estar en cualquier parte de pac-item. No necesariamente forma parte de pac-item-query y podría estar parcialmente en pac-item-query y en el texto restante en pac-item. |